# JavaScript V4 containerized Azure Functions No job functions found

Tags: javascript, azure, docker, function, containers

Following this example on multiple operating systems results in the same error - No job functions found.

[JavaScript V4 containerized Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deploy-container?tabs=acr%2Cpowershell%2Cazure-cli&pivots=programming-language-javascript)

Reproducible Steps:

```
func --version => 4.0.5390

func init --worker-runtime node --language javascript --docker

func new --name HttpExample --template "HTTP trigger" --authlevel anonymous

docker build --tag exapt/azurefunctionsimage:v1.0.0 .

docker run -p 8080:80 exapt/azurefunctionsimage:v1.0.0
```

Always the same results No job functions are found and therefore No HTTP routes mapped

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

```
info: Host.Triggers.Warmup[0]
      Initializing Warmup Extension.
info: Host.Startup[503]
      Initializing Host. OperationId: '5578f731-bbdf-411f-b3d2-a6a79c7f6aeb'.
info: Host.Startup[504]
      Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, OperationId=5578f731-bbdf-411f-b3d2-a6a79c7f6aeb
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      LoggerFilterOptions
      {
        "MinLevel": "None",
        "Rules": [
          {
            "ProviderName": null,
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": null,
            "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": null,
            "CategoryName": "Host.Function.ToolingConsoleLog",
            "LogLevel": "Information",
            "Filter": null
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": "None",
            "Filter": null
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": null,
            "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
          }
        ]
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      ConcurrencyOptions
      {
        "DynamicConcurrencyEnabled": false,
        "MaximumFunctionConcurrency": 500,
        "CPUThreshold": 0.8,
        "SnapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
      {
        "BatchSize": 1000,
        "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
        "IsEnabled": true
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      SingletonOptions
      {
        "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
        "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:01:00",
        "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
        "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
        "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      ScaleOptions
      {
        "ScaleMetricsMaxAge": "00:02:00",
        "ScaleMetricsSampleInterval": "00:00:10",
        "MetricsPurgeEnabled": true,
        "IsTargetScalingEnabled": true,
        "IsRuntimeScalingEnabled": false
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.JobHostService[0]
      Starting JobHost
info: Host.Startup[401]
      Starting Host (HostId=8e98bfe4f974-2137340777, InstanceId=156a96ca-3e89-48f0-8b60-b377b15bf25e, Version=4.27.4.4, ProcessId=1, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=(null))
info: Host.Startup[314]
      Loading functions metadata
info: Host.Startup[326]
      Reading functions metadata (Custom)
info: Host.Startup[327]
      1 functions found (Custom)
info: Host.Startup[315]
      0 functions loaded
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Generating 0 job function(s)
warn: Host.Startup[0]
      No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      HttpOptions
      {
        "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
        "EnableChunkedRequestBinding": false,
        "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
        "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
        "RoutePrefix": "api"
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostHttpRoutesManager[0]
      Initializing function HTTP routes
      No HTTP routes mapped

info: Host.Startup[412]
      Host initialized (85ms)
info: Host.Startup[413]
      Host started (104ms)
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /azure-functions-host
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Host.General[337]
      Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000035830186'.

C:\data\git\azure-code\container-functions\javascript\4.x\unittest>docker run -p 8080:80 exapt/azurefunctionsimage:v1.0.0
info: Host.Triggers.Warmup[0]
      Initializing Warmup Extension.
info: Host.Startup[503]
      Initializing Host. OperationId: 'b1b6445b-4574-4558-b048-60a071d87f76'.
info: Host.Startup[504]
      Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, OperationId=b1b6445b-4574-4558-b048-60a071d87f76
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      LoggerFilterOptions
      {
        "MinLevel": "None",
        "Rules": [
          {
            "ProviderName": null,
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": null,
            "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": null,
            "CategoryName": "Host.Function.ToolingConsoleLog",
            "LogLevel": "Information",
            "Filter": null
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": "None",
            "Filter": null
          },
          {
            "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
            "CategoryName": null,
            "LogLevel": null,
            "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
          }
        ]
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      ConcurrencyOptions
      {
        "DynamicConcurrencyEnabled": false,
        "MaximumFunctionConcurrency": 500,
        "CPUThreshold": 0.8,
        "SnapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
      {
        "BatchSize": 1000,
        "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
        "IsEnabled": true
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      SingletonOptions
      {
        "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
        "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:01:00",
        "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
        "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
        "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      ScaleOptions
      {
        "ScaleMetricsMaxAge": "00:02:00",
        "ScaleMetricsSampleInterval": "00:00:10",
        "MetricsPurgeEnabled": true,
        "IsTargetScalingEnabled": true,
        "IsRuntimeScalingEnabled": false
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.JobHostService[0]
      Starting JobHost
info: Host.Startup[401]
      Starting Host (HostId=849995b3309d-2137340777, InstanceId=4e06d01f-fea7-45d0-b16e-ba2394417010, Version=4.27.4.4, ProcessId=1, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=(null))
info: Host.Startup[314]
      Loading functions metadata
info: Host.Startup[326]
      Reading functions metadata (Custom)
info: Host.Startup[327]
      1 functions found (Custom)
info: Host.Startup[315]
      0 functions loaded
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Generating 0 job function(s)
warn: Host.Startup[0]
      No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
      HttpOptions
      {
        "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
        "EnableChunkedRequestBinding": false,
        "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
        "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
        "RoutePrefix": "api"
      }
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostHttpRoutesManager[0]
      Initializing function HTTP routes
      No HTTP routes mapped

info: Host.Startup[412]
      Host initialized (84ms)
info: Host.Startup[413]
      Host started (103ms)
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /azure-functions-host
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Host.General[337]
      Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000819BC0C8'.
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the commands mentioned in the above, I also got the same error.
check below:

[image]

When I used the commands, they didn't create a function.json file.
I added function.json to my httptrigger function, which is given below:

**function.json:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "Anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger.",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is my folder structure and status after added function.json:

[image]

By using two commands I was successfully build and run the docker file.
`docker build --tag exapt/azurefunctionsimage:v1.0.0 .` and
`docker run -p 8080:80 exapt/azurefunctionsimage:v1.0.0`

**Output in Local:**

[image]

**Output in Docker:**

[image]

Comment: what is your Azure Functions Core Tools version:

func --version

And what does your function code look like, as for v4 you are not required to add a function.json file as per https://aka.ms/AzFuncNodeV4

Comment: @Exapter, My azure function core tool version is v4, but whenever I added the function.json iam able to load the function in docker. Before added that function is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

For v4 try using :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-nightly-node18
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
    npm install && \
    npm run build
```